# Use GMSCircle as hole of a polygon instead of GMSPath

Tags: swift, xcode, google-maps, polygon

I have a polygon shape with a square hole punched out, I've been fiddling with trying to do the same but with a circle, GMSCircle, but haven't had any luck.

Would anyone know the proper way to do it?

Here is my current code block for the polygon hole.

```
    let polygon = GMSPolygon()
    polygon.path = GMSPath(path: northAmericaPolygon)
    polygon.holes = [GMSPath(path: sanFranciscoHole)]
    polygon.fillColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.2)
    polygon.strokeColor = .black
    polygon.strokeWidth = 2
    polygon.map = mapView
```